# when I use react-redux-router and reroute to the old page the state does not get flushed and everything is added on top of the old state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am new to react and redux  and I am facing a very strange issue and it is almost a week that I am trying different ways but no result. I have two component channel and its children. This is how it works: first the channel gets a list of channel from the server and then it in channel component there is a loop which send each channel to the storyboard then in storyboard I call another ajax call to get a list of stories for that specific channel. So here in storyboard as you can see I need to have my reducer separated from channel reducer since when I mix them there will be an infinite loop and browser crashes. Anyway this works on load and even when I use a button just for test and I updated channel reducer with the new channel list and it works perfectly fine, by that I mean it loads all channels and related stories with a fresh state. However when I used routing this never works as expected. For more explanation I use react-redux-router to make sure all the states are synchronized. So when I use router and and I load another page then when I get back to my channel page everything is repeated twice. so for instance if I have 2 channel with 3 stories in each, then in the result page after routing I have 4 channels with 6 stories in each channel. This means that react does not clear the states and adds everything on top of current state Here is my code:

```
       import React from "react";
   import {connect} from "react-redux";
   import StoryBoard from '../story-board/StoryBoard';
   import {getChannels} from './action/ChannelAction';
   import  {updateChannels} from './action/ChannelUpdateAction';
   import  {cleanStoryBoards} from '../story-board/story-board-action/CleanStoryBoardsAction';
   class Channel extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super();

   }
   componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getChannels();

    }

    render() {
       return (
          <div>

            <div className="col-xs-12  col-md-8 col-lg-8 paddingStoryBoardsDownJs dummyEachChannelStoryBoard">
                <div className="row">

                    {
                        this.props.channels.channelsArr.map((item, i) => <StoryBoard 
                                                                                     newsChanel={item}
                                                                                     idForDummySetUp={i + 1}
                                                                                     key={"storyBoard" + i}
                                                                                     channelsInfo={{
                                                                                         "channelsCount": this.props.channels.channelsArr.length,
                                                                                         "channelIndex": i
                                                                                     }}></StoryBoard>)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>


            <div className="col-xs-12  col-md-2 col-lg-2 color2">.col-sm-4</div>
        </div>

         );
       }
    }

     const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        channels: state.channelReducer
      };
    };

     const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
       getChannels: () => {
          dispatch(getChannels());

            } 
    };
   };
      export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Channel);
```

And also in channel action I have:

```
        export function getChannels(){

            return dispatch => {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:3003/jsonchannel.txt",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            var arr=[];
                            for (var key in data.channelList) {
                                arr.push(data.channelList[key].capitalizeFirstLetter());
                            }
                            dispatch({
                                type: "GET_CHANNEL",
                                payload: arr

                            });
                        }.bind(this)
                    });
                };
        }
```

And in channel reducer I have:

```
            const ChannelReducer = (state ={"channelsArr":[],"channelLabelForScrolls":[]}, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case "GET_CHANNEL":
                    state={"channelsArr":action.payload};
                    break;
            }
            return state;
        };
        export  default  ChannelReducer;
```

Also my storyboard is as follows:

```
        import  React from "react";
        import {connect} from "react-redux";
        import  {getStoriesAction} from './story-board-action/StoryBoardAction';
        import  {HamburgerMenu} from './storyboard-classes/HamburgerMenuShouldBeRemoved';
        class StoryBoard extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super();
            }
            componentDidMount() {
                /**Loading Stories**/
                this.props.getStories(this.props.newsChanel);
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div id={"dummyStoryBoardHeaderRowJs" + this.props.idForDummySetUp}
                             className="row storyBoardHeaderRowJs">
                            <StoryBoardHeader idForDummySetUp={this.props.idForDummySetUp} newsChanel={this.props.newsChanel}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row" id={"channelPositionFinder" + this.props.newsChanel.removeAllSpaces()}>
                            {
                                //this.props.stories.map((item,i)=> <Story key={i} position={i} story={item} ></Story>)
                                this.props.stories.map(function (snippet) {
                                    if ( snippet.channel.toLowerCase() === this.props.newsChanel.toLowerCase()) {
                                        return (
                                            snippet.storiesSnippet.map((item, i) => <Story key={i} story={item}
                                                                                           channel={this.props.newsChanel}></Story>)
                                        );

                                    }
                                }.bind(this)) //bind thid to outer loop to mae parent this valid
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
            componentDidUpdate() {

            }
        }
        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            return {
                stories: state.storyBoardReducer
            };
        };
        //which actions we wanna use in this components
        const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
            return {
                getStories: (chanel) => {
                    dispatch(getStoriesAction(chanel));

                }

            };
        };
        export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoryBoard);
```

and my story action is as follows:

```
            export function getStoriesAction(channel){

                return dispatch => {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:3003/"+channel.replace(/\s+/g, '')+".txt",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            var storiesSnoppet=[];
                            for (var key in data) {
                                storiesSnoppet.push(data[key]);
                            }
                            console.log("channel:  "+channel  );
                            console.log(storiesSnoppet);
                            dispatch({
                                type: "SET_STORIES",
                                payload: {"channel":channel,"storiesSnippet":storiesSnoppet}

                            });
                        }.bind(this)
                    });
                };

        }
```

and finally reducer for storyboard is as follows:

```
            const StoryBoardReducer = (state =[], action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case "SET_STORIES":
                    var tempStateStories = state.slice();
                    tempStateStories.push(action.payload);
                    state=tempStateStories;
                    break;
            }
            return state;
        };
        export  default  StoryBoardReducer;
```

As far as I know I took everything into account and everything works but when I use routing channels and stories inside each channel gets doubled which means that react router adds channels and stories on top of the old state rather than starting with fresh new state. For sake space I did not added the pages which rerout back to channel since it is simply a link. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use the componentWillUnmount() life cycle method to clear the state before you navigate to another page.

Comment: @cdaiga thanks a lot for answering so by clearing the state should I do it manually like state=[] or tehre is a way that I  am not aware of?

Comment: Yes something like that! Provide a props method to flush the state you are reading from, and use it in the `componentWillUnmount()` method.

Comment: @cdaiga Man you fixed one of my biggest problem during last week. Could you please add it as an answer for future new react developers?

Comment: Hahaha, @Hamed Minaee, I am also a react newbie.

Comment: @cdaiga Thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the componentWillUnmount() life cycle method to clear the state before you navigate to another page. Provide a props method to flush the state you are reading from, and use it in the componentWillUnmount() method of this component.